# Why are my PHP objects passed by reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment

I'm seeing some confusing behavior related to reference/assignment in PHP...

```
private function doSomething($things)
{
    foreach ($things as $thing) {
        echo $thing->property; // 'foobar'
        $copyThing = $thing;
        unset($copyThing->property);
        echo $thing->property; // undefined
```

I expect this behavior when passing variables by reference (`&$thing`) but I'm not trying to do that here and it seems to be happening anyway. What am I missing?

Comment: objects in foreach loops are always passed by reference

Comment: $thing is already a passed reference of $things as your in a foreach loop

Comment: @M.M Whoa! Did that default change in any recent versions of PHP? I swear I remember having to use `&$var` to overtly pass by reference.

Comment: And is there a way to UN-pass by reference?

Comment: `In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference. ` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: If it's an object, then no.... because a variable holding an object is always a pointer

Comment: You would need to `clone` your object, for instance:
`foreach ($things as $thing) {
   $copyThing = clone $thing;
   unset($copyThing->property);
}`

Comment: @emersonthis perhaps talking about PHP 4? At least since PHP 5.0 (that's more than 10 years ago!) objects are always assigned by-object, i.e. it's it's an object pointer being passed around, the contents are always equal for every "pointer" to that object. Use `clone` if you need a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just explaining my comment:

> objects in foreach loops are always passed by reference

When you use a foreach loop for an array of objects the variable that you are using inside the loop is a pointer to that object so it works as a reference, any change on the object inside the loop is a change on the object outside.
This is because:

> objects are always passed by reference (@user3137702 quote)

Detailed and official explanation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

---

When you copy and unset your variable:

> ```
> $copyThing = $thing;
> unset($copyThing->property);
> ```

you are creating another pointer and unseting it, so the original value is a gone. As a matter of fact, since the foreach loop also uses a pointer the `$things` array is also affected.

check this [ideone](http://ideone.com/ufF0tQ) (notice the vardump [where the 'a' property is gone], as the output is the same as you got)

---

I do not know in which version it changed, if ever, as it seems like default object/pointer behavior

---

As a workaround (some ideas):

1. Copy your initial array
2. Use [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php): `$x = clone($obj);` (As long as the default copy constructor works for your objects)

Comment: I would amend this to simply say "objects are always passed by reference" , as this behavior doesn't really have anything to do with a foreach loop.

Comment: Aha! I get it now. I initially misunderstood it to be about all foreach loops... but now I understand that it's unique to objects. Is it correct that if I contstructed the exact same example but instead of `unset`ing object properties I `unset` keys in an array it would _not_ be by reference?

Comment: Yes, correct. you would be unsetting the copy, just because: [ideone](http://ideone.com/LDvfIl)

Comment: @M.M Is there a way to prevent this default behavior? In other words, is there a way I can just copy the object without effecting the original?

Comment: @emersonthis as I said in the **workaround** part of the answer you could use [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) to copy your object to another variable (another memory location so there would be a new pointer)